# Matlab: OOPS : Event Block: Dynamically (Programmatically) adding events at run-time

Tags: matlab, events, dynamic

I am trying to write a matlab class which accepts request for financial data and later asynchronously provides the data by triggering events. The whole logic can be defined as following.

1) Get request for data on Security (SecId) with a callback func handle (@func)

2) Add a listener  with event name "evnt_SecId" and callback func @func.

3) Collect all data, filter them by securities and fire event specific to a particular security.

Now everything seems to be easy and doable in Matlab except that I cannot **dynamically define events**. Currently, I must define events for each SecId in the { events ... end } block.

Does anyone knows of a way to dynamically declare events as the request arrive?

**Alternate Solution that I thought of** : I can have one update "event" and all listener associated with it while the filtering for SecId takes place in the callbacks. This solution is unacceptable due to performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

1. make SecId a subclass of dynamicprops
2. instead of adding a regular listener, add a PostSet propListener and dynamically add a
   new property
3. send the message by setting the value of the property.

I have no idea about the performance characteristics of that solution, but it might do what you need.

Comment: I like this way of handling the events. However, I have eventData as well that I want to transport to the listener callbacks. With property events I have no control over the eventData, right?

Comment: Found an easier way: Instead of addressing different event listener by different events the better way is to have single common event but to have multiple object associated with each SecId. No need to even go via dynamic property rout as I anyway manage a list of all SecId objects. Thanks a lot Sam for giving direction on this.

Comment: Sounds like you've found a better solution. Just FYI, if you wanted to do the dynamicprops and propListener route - you're right, you wouldn't have control over the event data, but you could use the value of the property that you were setting instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about filtering for the SecId in the "master" event firing method? This way the filtering only happens once per fired event. The class must than associated the listeners it has with the SecId it was registered for.